# m.2 ssd for MSI PRO A620M-E Motherboard, sata or nvme?

Tags: ssd, sata, m.2, nvme

for this motherboard: MSI Pro A620M-E
https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/PRO-A620M-E
amazon link: [https://www.amazon.com/MSI-PRO-A620M-ProSeries-Motherboard/dp/B0C15SRJNM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C15SRJNM)

in getting an M.2 SSD, either in 1tb or 2tb in size, do I get an M.2 SATA or M.2 NVMe ?

from various spec statements, all I see is *1 x M Key 2260, 2280 (PCIe 4.0 x4)*

from MSI they only state `1x M.2 M.2_1 Source (From CPU) supports up to PCIe 4.0 x4 , supports 2280/2260 devices, 4x SATA 6G`

for a 2280 size M.2, does sata type work in nvme mobo slot but not the other way around?

Comment: I have seen SATA SSDs working in an NVMe slot but I don't know if A620 also supports that (that was on B450). If you want to be safe go NVMe